# Gtk keypress modifiers

Tags: gtk

I try to check if control key is pressed but I can't.
According to documentation I try this:

```
G_MODULE_EXPORT gboolean
KEYPRESS_window1(GtkWidget *window1, GdkEventKey* pKey, gpointer user_data)
{
    guint modifiers;
    modifiers = gtk_accelerator_get_default_mod_mask();

    g_print("modifiers   %d\n", modifiers);
    g_print("pKey->state %d\n", pKey->state);

    if ((pKey->state & modifiers) == GDK_CONTROL_MASK)
    {
        ctrlpressed = 1;
        return TRUE;
    }
return FALSE;
}
```

Signals are raised and passes correctly but logic dont passes "if" condition.
I would like to know why, so please help.

Comment: what do the `g_print()` statements print?

Comment: modifiers   469762061
pKey->state 16
pKey->state varies depend of capslock, numlock and so, modifiers seems not changes at all.

Comment: `modifiers` shouldn't change, unless you change the default mod mask yourself. This code works for me - if I replace the `ctrlpressed = 1` line with `g_print("Ctrl pressed\n")`, I see `Ctrl pressed` every time I press a key combination like Ctrl+G.

Comment: Yes, this is it! When I pressed ctrl+G also works! But I need to check and set "ctrlpressed" with just control key pressed with no other keys.

Comment: Oh... I guess I can give you a useful answer now ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is just pressed by itself, you need to examine the key code of the pressed key. You should be able to examine the `keyval` field of the event and check for `GDK_KEY_Control_L` or `GDK_KEY_Control_R`. You could also check the `hardware_keycode` field, but I don't know if that's portable.

Comment: Yes, with "if (pKey->keyval == GDK_KEY_Control_L)" my GUI works as expected. Why I don't see so simple and logical solution before? :) Thank you very much.